# Discordjs client doesn't receive events

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My client should receive and handle interactions (slash commands) but doesn't receive anything instead

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
//disc = require("discord.js");
const axios = require("axios");

const token = process.env.BOT_TOKEN;

const client = new Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
  hook_commands();
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    console.log("interaction created");
});


client.login(token);


function hook_commands() {
//redacted, it works fine
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but try adding intents `new Client({ intents: 34435 })`, that will include all intents. ___ And also, make sure you're registering the slash commands by doing something like [this](https://github.com/alaanvv/Verse-Music/blob/main/lib/uploadSlashCommands.js)

Answer (score 1):

try to add intents but other than that i dont see anything wrong with it

```
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.DirectMessageReactions,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.DirectMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.DirectMessageTyping,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildModeration,
    ],
});
```